# Why do compiled programs create a copy with ~?

Tags: ubuntu, files, filenames

Why is it that when I run programs for the first time it creates a copy of that file with a ~ at the end? For example, a file like `HelloWorld.lua` when run would create 2 files: `HelloWorld.lua` and `HelloWorld.lua~`. What is the purpose of this happening?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If file `foo` has a sibling `foo~` the file with a tilde is likely a by-product, backup, or intermediate file for either your compiler or editor.

They're usually cleaned up automatically, ignored by your version control, and hidden in guis.

Thinks of it as one of those things that most people aren't familiar with and you probably don't want to deal with, unless you're *certain* you need it — kinda like toupees and colostomy bags.

Answer (score 5):

This is not about "compiling" a program, or even related to coding.
This is your text editor creating a backup file.

Your text editor (I assume `gedit` in this case, but correct me if I am wrong) seems to be configured to create a backup file by default. You should observe this behavior with *any* text file you edit.

Check [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/questions/83026/prevent-gedit-from-creating-files-with-the-tilde-suffix) for a solution.